# Adding extra field in aws appsync resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a many-to-many relation between users and groups in my schema, with a extra enum field for the relation level. I am able to add the extra relation field to my dataset, but I get schema validation error:

> "The provided key element does not match the schema (Service:
>   AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
>   Request ID: 2615V0KG8272IHVENE3DBSBCTVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"

*Schema:*

```
type Group {
    id: ID!
    created: AWSDateTime!
    createdById: ID!
    createdBy: User!
    title: String!
    description: String
    users(first: Int, after: String): GroupUsersConnection
}

enum GroupRoles {
    admin
    user
}

type GroupUsers {
    id: ID!
    created: AWSDateTime!
    role: GroupRoles!
    userId: ID!
    groupId: ID!
}

type GroupConnection {
    items: [Group]
    nextToken: String
}

type GroupUsersConnection {
    items: [UserWithRole]
    nextToken: String
}

type Mutation {
    createGroup(input: CreateGroupInput!): Group
    createUser(input: CreateUserInput!): User
    createGroupUsers(input: CreateGroupUsersInput!): GroupUsers
}

type Query {
    getGroup(id: ID!): Group
    listGroups(filter: TableGroupFilterInput, limit: Int, nextToken: String): GroupConnection   
    getUser(id: ID!): User
    listUsers(filter: TableUserFilterInput, limit: Int, nextToken: String): UserConnection
}

input TableGroupFilterInput {
    id: TableIDFilterInput
    created: TableStringFilterInput
    createdById: TableIDFilterInput
    title: TableStringFilterInput
    description: TableStringFilterInput
}

input TableUserFilterInput {
    id: TableIDFilterInput
    created: TableStringFilterInput
    email: TableStringFilterInput
    password: TableStringFilterInput
    name: TableStringFilterInput
    avatar: TableStringFilterInput
    isOnline: TableBooleanFilterInput
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    created: AWSDateTime!
    email: AWSEmail!
    password: String!
    name: String
    avatar: String
    isOnline: Boolean!
    groups(first: Int, after: String): UserGroupsConnection
}

type UserConnection {
    items: [User]
    nextToken: String
}

type UserGroupsConnection {
    items: [Group]
    nextToken: String
}

type UserWithRole {
    id: ID!
    created: AWSDateTime!
    email: AWSEmail!
    password: String!
    name: String
    avatar: String
    isOnline: Boolean!
    role: GroupRoles!
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}
```

*Resolver for `GroupUsersConnection.items` with `UserTable` as datasource:*

```
##--------------------------
## request mapping template
##--------------------------
#if( ${ctx.source.items.isEmpty()} )
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Scan",
    "consistentRead": true
}
#else
  #set($userIds = [])
  #foreach($groupUser in ${ctx.source.items})    
      #set($userIdMap = {})
      $util.qr($userIdMap.put("id", $util.dynamodb.toString($groupUser.get("userId"))))
      $util.qr($userIds.add($userIdMap))
  #end

  {
      "version" : "2018-05-29",
      "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
      "tables" : {
          "UserTable": {
              "keys": $util.toJson($userIds),
              "consistentRead": true
          }
      }
  }
#end

##--------------------------
## response mapping template
##--------------------------
#if ( ! ${ctx.result.data} )
    $util.toJson([])
#else
    #foreach($user in ${ctx.result.data.UserTable})
        #set($idx = $foreach.count-1)
        #set($role = $ctx.source.items.get(0).get("role"))
        $util.qr($user.put("role", $role))
        $util.qr($usersWithRoles.add($user))        
    #end
    $util.toJson($ctx.result.data.UserTable)
#end
```

*This is the query I try to run, with full result:*

```
query ListGroups {
  listGroups {
    items {
      id
      title
      createdById
      createdBy {
        name
        email
      }
      users {
        items {
          id
          name
          role
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "data": {
    "listGroups": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "72423554-fe02-4644-92e4-4bd2a2702d85",
          "title": "My first group",
          "createdById": "e626fab4-b099-4736-91f0-dcbf5fc2e47e",
          "createdBy": {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john@doe.com"
          },
          "users": {
            "items": [
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "listGroups",
        "items",
        0,
        "users",
        "items",
        0,
        "role"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 105,
          "column": 11,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: NB3G15C13BUMEQ3OK6VPNVA3LFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a 400 error, which could mean that your request mapping template structure does not match the Amazon DynamoDB key structure.

Please enable CloudWatch logs (with "ALL" option) from the Settings page of your API. Once you do, run the same query again. This will log the evaluated RequestMapping Template in the logs. You can then introspect the query to DynamoDB, and compare it with your table schema. There should be mismatch in one of the calls.

The "fieldInError" boolean field in the mapping template log indicates whether the resolution of a particular path succeeded, so you can just introspect the failed ones.